# Populate ListView with Selected Image File Path

Tags: android

Im using the following code to select some images.I want to populate Paths of the selected images to a ListView

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     try {

         // When an Image is picked
         if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                 && null != data) {
             // Get the Image from data

             String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
             imagesEncodedList = new ArrayList<String>();
             if(data.getData()!=null){

                 Uri mImageUri=data.getData();

                 // Get the cursor
                 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mImageUri,
                         filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                 // Move to first row
                 cursor.moveToFirst();

                 int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                 imageEncoded  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                 cursor.close();

             }else {
                 if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                     ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
                     ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                     for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                         ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                         Uri uri = item.getUri();
                         mArrayUri.add(uri);
                         // Get the cursor
                         Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                         // Move to first row
                         cursor.moveToFirst();

                         int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                         imageEncoded  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                         imagesEncodedList.add(imageEncoded);
                         cursor.close();

                     }
                   //  ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main, imagesEncodedList);

                   //  ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.imagelist);
                   //  listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                     Log.v("LOG_TAG", "Selected Images" + mArrayUri.size());
                     Toast.makeText(this,imagesEncodedList.get(0),
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
             }
         } else {
             Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                 .show();
     }
```

Tried doing this

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,    R.layout.activity_main, imagesEncodedList);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.imagelist);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Does not work,since array adapter does not accept this argument.Please advice.

Comment: ArrayAdapter takes Context as first parameter. are you getting any error when passing `this` or CurrentActivityName.this ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your below lines

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,    R.layout.activity_main, imagesEncodedList);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.imagelist);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

with

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1, imagesEncodedList);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.imagelist);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Write below line out of if/else condition:

```
imagesEncodedList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: 07-11 15:33:58.361: E/AndroidRuntime(25880): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 15:33:58.361: E/AndroidRuntime(25880): Process: com.example.mytestproject, PID: 25880
07-11 15:33:58.361: E/AndroidRuntime(25880): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: Did you try to print your imagesEncodedList?I think that list contains error.

Comment: Tried ` Log.v("hmm",imagesEncodedList.toString());` .Its printing [null,null]